# how to move bones with one bone move?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I saw tutorial in youtube that in POSE MODE , all of bones had box around them and when the bone was moving, parent bones also moved.how to do this?

[this is a tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0u_MYZCT3c)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the appearance of your bones to boxes called b-bones.

[image: b-bone]

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> you can change the thickness of the b-bone in edit mode. 
And If you want to make your bone see trough, go to your object properties and under Display, change the maximum draw type to wire

[image: Maximum draw type to wire]

And Bones can affect their parents with the bone constraint: Inverse Kinematic.

[Inverse Kinematic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/posing/bone_constraints/inverse_kinematics/introduction.html)

Comment: thanks...inverse Kinematic works but b-bone add box with fill-edges.in above image,boxes have no edge

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but if you want the b-bone to be  seen through: I added some information to my answer.